# Invest in stock, ETF etc. for a minimum amount of time?

Tags: stocks, investing, etf, stock-markets, long-term

Is there any financial product that would allow someone to invest a sum X (once or maybe periodically) in a single stock, an ETF or similar for a minimum of say 25, 50 or even 100 years?

I'm not asking about a product that guarantees a certain/higher ROI because of the long-term investment (i.e. fixed deposit); the question is more about preventing the owner from shortsighted decisions.

For example, if someone wanted to invest money in the stock market for their grand grand children (which have not born yet), is there a way to ensure the money stays invested until a substantial increase in value has likely happened, and to prevent intermediate generations from selling earlier?

Comment: Consider an irrevocable trust.  For the most part, it cannot be modified or revoked.

Comment: @BobBaerker I suppose that's not possible in EU countries?

Comment: Trusts are available in some European countries.  If that's where you are located, check with a local  estate planning lawyer.